# How to find closest exponential approximation?

Tags: approximation

I have a bunch of data, and I'd like to find the closest exponential aproximation I can to fit the points.  I'm guessing there's a (relatively) straightforward way to do this.

For example, if I have the data points (5, 9, 17, 33), the equation I'd be looking for would be f(n) = 2^x + 1, since that would fit the data points exactly.  Of course, if I had a similar set of points (5, 9, 16, 33), the equation wouldn't work quite right: f(n) = 2^x + 1 would still be "close", but presumably some other numbers than 2 and 1 could get me ever so slightly "closer".

Is there a way to figure this out?  (I'm guessing "yes").  Ideally, I'd like to have it be in the form described above (something^x + possible_constant), though methods for figuring this out in a more general way are welcome, so long as I can tie down some of the parameters (so that any other factors would be forced to be 0).

Comment: Take the logarithm and do a linear regression.

Comment: @Qiaochu: This works if you *multiply* rather than *add* the constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.xuru.org/rt/ExpR.asp#CopyPaste) is an online exponential regression calculator.

Comment: This uses Least Squares Fit!  I thought that might be the tool I'd need, but it was so long ago that I used it (~20 years) that I was afraid of embarrassing myself by mentioning it.

Comment: This solved my immediate problem.  And I can re-look up how to do LSF if I need it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve for $f(x) = Ca^x$ using linear regression, since $\log f(x) = (\log a)x + \log C$. Here $x$ should be $1,2,\ldots$, and $y$ should be your data points.

Comment: One of these days I'll find out why my browser insists on displaying equations as garbage...after I decode this answer, I'll let you know.

Comment: @Beska:  try downloading MathJax to see the equations

Comment: @Ross: Domo arigato gozaimasu.